# How to create slots in amazon lexv2 using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-lex

They have recently merged lexv2 resources, I'm not able to find proper way to create slots in lexv2 using terraform

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lexv2models_slot

Can someone share sample code for creating slots in lexv2 using terraform?